# Multi pickup per delivery with disjunction fails to find partial solution

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

Using OR-tools I am trying to model a multi pickup per delivery problem with disjunctions where delivery can be fulfiled only when all pickups were viseted prior to delivery arrival and can't get the solver to find partial solutions.
In the toy example below the solver returns an empty solution while it can fulfil the first 2 pickups and its delivery within its given MAX_ROUTE_TIME limit. Am I setting the multi pickup per delivery correctly?

I tried without success the following approaches:

1. Adding a constraint that pickups of the same delivery should be assigned to the same vehicle.
2. Splitting delivery nodes into 2, setting pickup and delivery to each pair of pickup-delivery and setting same vehicle constraints and same cumulative value.
3. Setting 0 penalty for pickups while same high penalty for deliveries.

```
import numpy as np
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2, pywrapcp


manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(7, 1, 0)
routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)
dim_name = 'Time'
durations = np.array(
  [[  0,   1,   1,   1, 100, 100, 100],
   [  1,   0,   1,   1, 100, 100, 100],
   [  1,   1,   0,   1, 100, 100, 100],
   [  1,   1,   1,   0, 100, 100, 100],
   [100, 100, 100, 100, 0,   100, 100],
   [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0,   100],
   [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0]])

def duration_callback(from_index, to_index):
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return durations[from_node][to_node]
    
transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(duration_callback)
routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
MAX_ROUTE_TIME = 400
routing.AddDimension(transit_callback_index, 0, MAX_ROUTE_TIME, True, dim_name)
time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dim_name)

pickups_deliveries = [
    (1, 3),
    (2, 3),
    (4, 6),
    (5, 6)
]

for pickup, delivery in pickups_deliveries:
    pickup_index = manager.NodeToIndex(pickup)
    delivery_index = manager.NodeToIndex(delivery)
    routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(pickup_index, delivery_index)
    routing.solver().Add(routing.VehicleVar(pickup_index) == routing.VehicleVar(delivery_index))
    routing.solver().Add(time_dimension.CumulVar(pickup_index) <= time_dimension.CumulVar(delivery_index))

for node in range(1, 7):
    routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(node)], 10000000)

search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.AUTOMATIC
search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH
search_parameters.lns_time_limit.seconds = 2
search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 5
solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

vehicle_id = 0
index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
node = manager.IndexToNode(index)
while not routing.IsEnd(index):
    previous_node = node
    previous_index = index
    index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
    node = manager.IndexToNode(index)
    print(previous_node, node ,durations[previous_node, node])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to drop the whole delivery in such cases

In this case, instead of using one disjunction per node you can use one disjunction per set of node `[1,2,3]` or `[4,5,6]`.

```py
routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(i) for i in (1,2,3,7)], 10000000, 4)
routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(i) for i in (4,5,6,8)], 10000000, 4)

#for node in range(1, 9):
#    routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(node)], 10000000)
```

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/a0a56698ba8fd07b7f84aee4fc45d891a8cd9828/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L570-L588

possible output:

```sh
[127]─[~/work/tmp/issue]
[>_<]─mizux@nuc10i7 %./so_2020_09_06_2.py
objective: 10000004
Dropped nodes: 4 5 6 8
0 -> 2 (1)
2 -> 1 (1)
1 -> 7 (1)
7 -> 3 (0)
3 -> 0 (1)
[0]─[~/work/tmp/issue]
[^v^]─mizux@nuc10i7 %
```

Answer (score 2):

You must duplicate the node `3` and `6` i.e. node can't be part of two different P&D...

ultra ugly fix (ed I used the Python 3.6+ f-string syntax (^v^) ):

```py
...
manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(7+2, 1, 0)
...
def duration_callback(from_index, to_index):
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        if from_node == 7:
            from_node = 3
        if from_node == 8:
            from_node = 6
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        if to_node == 7:
            to_node = 3
        if to_node == 8:
            to_node = 6
        return durations[from_node][to_node]

...
for node in range(1, 9):
    routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(node)], 10000000)
...

print(f"objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}")

# Display dropped nodes.
dropped_nodes = 'Dropped nodes:'
for node in range(routing.Size()):
    if routing.IsStart(node) or routing.IsEnd(node):
        continue
    if solution.Value(routing.NextVar(node)) == node:
        dropped_nodes += ' {}'.format(manager.IndexToNode(node))
print(dropped_nodes)

vehicle_id = 0
index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
node = manager.IndexToNode(index)
while not routing.IsEnd(index):
    previous_node = node
    pmap = previous_node
    if pmap == 7:
        pmap = 3
    if pmap == 8:
        pmap = 6
    previous_index = index
    index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
    node = manager.IndexToNode(index)
    nmap = node
    if nmap == 7:
        nmap = 3
    if nmap == 8:
        nmap = 6
    print(f"{previous_node} -> {node} ({durations[pmap, nmap]})")
```

possible output:

```sh
[0]─[~/work/tmp/issue]
[^v^]─mizux@nuc10i7 %./so_2020_09_06.py
objective: 20000303
Dropped nodes: 5 8
0 -> 4 (100)
4 -> 6 (100)
6 -> 2 (100)
2 -> 1 (1)
1 -> 7 (1)
7 -> 3 (0)
3 -> 0 (1)
[0]─[~/work/tmp/issue]
[^v^]─mizux@nuc10i7 %
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help the proposed logic accepts solutions including partial deliveries while I would like to drop the whole delivery in such cases, i.e. to only provide deliveries including goods from all pickup locations. Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @Mizux, is it allowed to have one single point as part of multiple pickups/deliveries?

Comment: no. One point can only be one delivery or one pickup.